# Como verificar os logs do PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, log

Possuo um banco de dados legado que ao fazer determinada ação no sistema que tem acesso a ele, varias tabelas são modificadas, consegui identificar no mínimo 04 tabelas sendo alteradas. Minha dúvida é existe um arquivo de `log` do **PostgreSQL** para que eu possa ter certeza quais tabelas foram alteradas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível fazer com que o servidor registre em `LOG` todos os comandos (`DDL`, `DML`, `DCL` e `TCL`) executados nas databases que nele estão hospedadas.

No arquivo de configurações `data/postgresql.conf` do seu servidor Postgres, ajuste os seguintes parametros:

```
log_statement = 'all'
log_destination = 'stderr'
logging_collector = on
log_min_duration_statement = 0
log_filename = 'postgresql-%F.log'
```

Seu servidor precisa ser reiniciado para que as alterações tenham efeito.

**Referências:**

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-logging.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgresql-queries

Answer (score 2):

Logs, no postgres, não registra alterações dos dados dos bancos, mas somente eventos relacioanados ao estado do *servidor*, tais como, startup, prontidão para conexoes e, principalmente, erros.

Veja um exemplo de log de um servidor em um sistema linux:

`$ tail /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.5-main.log`

> 2017-07-10 23:50:49 BRT [1165-2] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
>
> 2017-07-10 23:50:50 BRT [1165-3] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/5EBE9C8
>
> 2017-07-10 23:50:50 BRT [1165-4] LOG:  redo is not required
>
> 2017-07-10 23:50:50 BRT [1165-5] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound 
>   protections are now enabled
>
> 2017-07-10 23:50:50 BRT [1091-1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
>
> ...

Para fazer logs de alterações nos bancos dentro do servidor voce teria que criar estratégias de auditoria dentro de cada banco, uma sugestão interessante é apresentada no [wiki do postgres](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger), no caso voce tem que criar um trigger para cada tabela que vc queira auditar.

### [Audit trigger](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger)

Answer (score 0):

Não, o log do PostgreSQL só irá registrar as exceções e avisos. Se você está se referindo a alterações na estrutura da tabela, ficará mais difícil salvo se você criar um log na sua própria aplicação. Se está se referindo a alterações nos registros das tabelas, você deve criar "Triggers" para ser disparado nos eventos de atualização e gravar os campos e valores alterados numa tabela "Logs" que deve ser criada.

Answer (score 0):

Para identificar modificações na estrutura do banco executados por comandos `DDL`, utilize o recurso de `EVENT TRIGGER` do PostgreSQL. É um recurso que está disponível a partir da versão 9.3.

Com ele seria possível armazenar em uma tabela os dados das tabelas que estão sendo criadas pelo sistema legado e posteriormente consultar esses dados.

Crie uma tabela para armazenar os dados conforme os eventos forem ocorrendo.

```
create table auditoria (
    id serial,
    data_ocorrencia timestamp,
    dados jsonb
);
```

Crie uma função que retorne `event_trigger`. Observe o uso da função `pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()`, ela é que irá retornar os dados do objeto que está sendo modificado.

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION registra_evento_create()
    RETURNS event_trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
declare
    r record;
begin
    for r in 
        select jsonb_agg(evento) as eventos
        from (
            select
                pg_identify_object(classid,objid,objsubid) as obj
            from pg_event_trigger_ddl_commands()
        ) as evento
    loop
        execute 'insert into auditoria (data_ocorrencia, dados) values (current_timestamp,$1);'
            using (r.eventos);
    end loop;
end
$$;
```

Crie uma `EVENT TRIGGER`. Nesse caso irá ser disparada a trigger quando o comando for encerrado e for um comando `CREATE TABLE`. O parâmetro `WHEN` não é obrigatório, então seria possível auditar outros tipos de comandos `DDL`, na documentação são indicadas as opções.

```
CREATE EVENT TRIGGER tr_evento_create
ON ddl_command_end WHEN TAG IN ('CREATE TABLE')
EXECUTE PROCEDURE registra_evento_create();
```

Depois disso cada comando `CREATE TABLE` irá disparar a função `registra_evento_create()`, e com consultas na tabela `auditoria` seria possível identificar as tabelas que estão sendo criadas pelo sistema legado.

Abaixo links referentes ao assunto na documentação do postgres:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createeventtrigger.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-trigger-table-rewrite-example.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-trigger-matrix.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/event-trigger-definition.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-event-triggers.html
http://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-9-3-feature-highlight-event-triggers/